# Android Runtime permissions fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, runtime

I absolutely tried every tutorial I could find and any question on stackoverflow, i think i'm missing something.

I have MainActivity and 3 fragments CallHistory, Contacts and Sync.

What I'm basically trying to do is request read_call_log; write_call_log when I access call history section; read_contacts; write_contacts when I access contacts section, etc. I need some pointers on this please.

LE: Forgot to mention, the app requests permission but then it just crashes over that dialog, allowing me to grant/deny permissions after the app is closed

In **CallHistory.java** I have this

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_history, container, false);
    CallLogListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CallLogListView);

    getCallHistory();

    return rootView;
}
```

***getCallHistory()*** resides in the **CallHistory.java** file

```
    public void getCallHistory() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG}, READ_CALL_LOG_PERMISSION_VALUE);
    } else {
        m_CallLog = new ArrayList<CallLog>();

        m_Cursor.moveToFirst();

        try {
            do {
                CallLog item = new CallLog();
                item.setCallLogType(m_Cursor.getString(m_Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
                item.setCallLogNumber( m_Cursor.getString(m_Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));
                item.setCallLogName(m_Cursor.getString(m_Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)));
                item.setCallLogDuration(m_Cursor.getString(m_Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                m_CallLog.add(item);
            } while(m_Cursor.moveToNext());
        } finally {
            if (!m_Cursor.isClosed()) {
                m_Cursor.close();
            }
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            m_CallLogAdapter = new CallLogAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, m_CallLog);
            CallLogListView.setAdapter(m_CallLogAdapter);
            CallLogListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {
                            "Send contact info",
                            "Send directions",
                            "Save contact"
                    };

                    phoneNumber = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toptext)).getText().toString();

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Action for " + phoneNumber);
                    builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder message = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            if(which == 0)
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sending contact details to " + phoneNumber + " ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                sendSms(phoneNumber, prefs.getString("edit_text_preference_1", getText(R.string.default_contact_sms).toString()));
                            }
                            else if(which == 1)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sending directions to " + phoneNumber + " ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                sendSms(phoneNumber, prefs.getString("edit_text_preference_2", getText(R.string.default_directions_sms).toString()));
                            }
                            else if(which == 2)
                            {
                                if(contactExists(getContext(), phoneNumber)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Contact already exists. Cheers!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Intent saveContactIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactsAdd.class);
                                    saveContactIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                                    startActivity(saveContactIntent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Other related functions from **MainActivity.java**

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Handle navigation fragments

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_call_history) {
        fragmentClass = CallHistory.class;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_contacts) {
        fragmentClass = Contacts.class;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_sync) {
        fragmentClass = Sync.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    fragmentClass = CallHistory.class;

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

LE - Crash log

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.wrapart.crm/uk.wrapart.crm.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{98fd835 18957:uk.wrapart.crm/u0a275} (pid=18957, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{98fd835 18957:uk.wrapart.crm/u0a275} (pid=18957, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4861)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5954)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2452)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1521)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:520)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
at uk.wrapart.crm.CallHistory.onCreateView(CallHistory.java:117)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6929)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
... 9 more
```

LE Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

LE: CallHistory.java fragment Override

```
     @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == READ_CALL_LOG_PERMISSION_VALUE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is granted
            getCallHistory();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your crash log

Comment: I updated with crash log, sorry

Comment: Please make sure to add permission for READ_CALL_LOG in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I have them in the android manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: So, can you please post your complete crash log

Comment: That's what I have from the developer console. I'm not sure what to send you

Comment: Have you overridden onRequestPermissionsResult in your fragment ??

Comment: Yes, i've updated my question with the Override